# less.css: reference other style definitions?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to reference other style definitions? For example, if I have a `btn` style like this:

```
.btn {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Is it possible to reference `.btn`'s `width` somewhere else? For example, something like:

```
#right_of_buttons {
    left: @{.btn.width} * 3; // ie, instead of hard-coding 150px * 3
}
```

I know this can be done by defining a variable:

```
@btn_width: 150px;
.btn { width: @btn_width }
```

But I'd rather not do that if I don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken in the original LESS you could reference a specific selector's properties:

```
#right_of_buttons {
  left: .btn[width] * 3;
}
```

But this has been dropped in the .js version. You can just use a variable instead:

```
@btnwidth: 150px;
.btn {
  width: @btnwidth;
}
#sidebar {
  left: @btnwidth * 3;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Untested, but according to the documentation, you can include javascript directly, so

```
#right_of_buttons {
   left: `document.getElementsByClassName('.btn')[0].style.width`
}
```

But at that point, I'm not sure how much savings that gets you over simply using a variable.

Comment: `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.  This runs under Node.js not in the browser, so `window` and `document` aren't present.